# Codeigniter User Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I've been trying to create a login function on a Codeigniter project by retrieving the username and password inputs from the form and comparing it to the database. However, with this current code I am getting my negative results message (echo 'bad'- just for testing) even though I use the correct username/password combination on the login form. I do have a separate function for the login page.

As of right now, I don't have any error messages. Any help or guidance to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Controller

```
 public function user_login()
   {   

      $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name'); 
      $password =   $this->input->post('password');

      $data = array( 

         'user_name' => $user_name,
         'password' =>  hash('sha256' , $password . 'SALT')
      );  

      $result = $this->user_model->login($data);
         if($result == TRUE){
             $sess_array = array(
              'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name')
      );
         } else 
         { 
          echo 'bad'; 
         } 

   }
```

Model

```
 public function login($data) 
   { 
      $condition = "user_name =" . "'" . $data['user_name'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";  
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('users');
      $this->db->where($condition);
      $this->db->limit(1);
      $query = $this->db->get();

      if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: if you are sure about ($query->num_rows() == 1) retuns you some records in your model , then you can try if($result) instead of if($result == TRUE) in your controllers

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
$q = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
    'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
    'password' => $data['password']
));

if (count($q->result())>0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Review comment: Please take care of code formatting (indent and comments) and take time to explain your answer and how it fix the problem of the Original Poster.

Answer (score 0):

Your model can be simplified.

```
public function login($data) 
{  
      $query = $this->db->get_where('users', $data);

      return $query->row();
  }
```

And then in your controller :

```
 //Stuff

 $result = $this->user_model->login($data);
 if($result)
      //Foo
 else
      //Bar
```